# Threads are created, then all exit before critical region

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, signal-processing, semaphore

I need to write a program for class that creates 8 threads.  4 producer, and 4 consumer.  The producers need to loop, and randomly send SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 to all consumer threads.  Only 2 should register if they have received SIGUSR1 and the other 2 register SIGUSR2.

When I try to run it all threads are created, "prod ready" is printed by all 4 producer threads,"waiting 1" is printed by both threads, but "waiting 2" is printed 3 times then all threads exit.  At the end of debugging it says that the process exits normally.

I need to use semaphores to control the critical regions.  Any help would be great.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define NP  4
#define NC1 2
#define NC2 2
#define CNT 10

void handler1(int signum);
void handler2(int signum);

typedef struct {
    int sent;
    int received;
    int buf[1];   
    int SIG1;              
    int SIG2;              
    sem_t con;         
    sem_t prod;          
} sbuf_t;

sbuf_t buff;

void *producer() {
    printf("prod ready \n");
    int s;
    while(1){
        sem_wait(&buff.prod);
        s=rand()%2;
        if(s==1){
            buff.sent++;
            kill(0,SIGUSR1);
        }
        else if(s==2){
            buff.sent++;
            kill(0,SIGUSR2);

        }sem_post(&buff.prod);
    }

}

void *consumer1() {
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
    printf("waiting 1\n");
    while(1){

    }
}

void *consumer2() {
    signal(SIGUSR2, handler2);
    printf("waiting 2\n");
    while(1){

    }
}

void handler1(int signum){
    if(signum==SIGUSR1){
        sem_wait(&buff.con);
        printf("Caught 1\n");
        buff.received++;
        buff.SIG1++;

        sem_post(&buff.con);
    }
}

void handler2(int signum){
    if(signum==SIGUSR2){
        sem_wait(&buff.con);
        printf("caught 2 \n");
        buff.received++;
        buff.SIG2++;

        sem_post(&buff.con);
    }
}

void main(){
    pthread_t threads[9];
    buff.SIG1=0;
    buff.SIG2=0;
    buff.sent=0;
    buff.received=0;
    int index;


        sem_init(&buff.con, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&buff.prod, 0, 0);
    for (index = 0; index < NP; index++) {
            pthread_create(&threads[index], NULL, producer,NULL);
        }
        for (index = 0;index < NC1;index++) {
            pthread_create(&threads[index+4], NULL, consumer1,NULL);
        }
    for (index = 0;index < NC2;index++) {
            pthread_create(&threads[index+6], NULL, consumer2,NULL);
        }
}
```

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width font.  Never use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: Iregardless of what Visual Studio will let you get away with; the `main()` function only has two valid signatures: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   I.E. they all have a return type of `int`.

Comment: When the code performs a comparison between a literal and anything else for equality, always place the literal on the left, so any keypunch error, like using `=` rather than `==` will be caught by the compiler rather than you spending hours and hours and getting gray hairs over a simple keypunch error.

Comment: There is a long list of functions that must not be used in a signal handler.  One of those forbidden functions is `printf()` as that 'can' result in a nested signal event, which will crash the program. Similar considerations exist for the function `sem_wait()`  Suggest reading the man page signals(7) for which functions can be called

Comment: in linux,  system V, and BSD the function: `signal()` is strongly discouraged from being used due its' non reliability and non consistent implementation.  It is strongly encouraged to use:  `sigaction()` instead.

Comment: the syntax for a thread function is: `void * threadName( void * )`    The threads in the program are using: `void * threadName()`  which is not quite the same

Comment: after this line: `s=rand()%2;`, the value in `s` will be 0 or 1,  NOT 1 or 2  so the code block starting with: `else if(s==2){` will never be executed

Comment: in the thread function: `producer()`, the call to `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` will not 'throttle' that function. but will cause each instance of that thread to execute sequentially.  probably not what you want.   In the functions: `handler1()` and `handler2()`, the calls to `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` will slow down the two handler? functions by causing them to be executed sequentially, but other wise have no effect.

Comment: NOTE: the `kill()` function sends a signal to a process, not to a specific thread.  This means the `main()` process, which is not setup to handle the two signals, will probably be killed.  probably not what you want.

Comment: the posted code needs to be checking the returned status from the calls to `signal()` and calls to `pthread_create()` to assure the operations were successful.

Comment: suggest the signal handler functions only call `sem_post()`.  Suggest the threads call `sem_wait()`. Suggest each consumer thread, at the beginning, call `sem_wait().  Suggest each producer thread call `sem_wait() on the same semaphore(s) as is used by the consumer threads so it waits for a consumer thread to be available before generating another signal.

Answer (score 0):

In the `main()` function, the threads are being created,

then `main()` exits.

When main() exits, all the threads are also exited.

Suggest reading about such functions as: `pthread_exit()` and `pthread_join()`

Note: the following has an error in the handling of the signals and in the handling of the semaphores, but will demonstrate the use of pthread_join() and pthread_exit()

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define NP  4
#define NC1 2
#define NC2 2
#define CNT 10

#define MAX_THREADS (9)

void handler1(int signum);
void handler2(int signum);

struct sbuf_t 
{
    int sent;
    int received;
    int buf[1];   
    int SIG1;              
    int SIG2;              
    sem_t con1;
    sem_t con2;         
    sem_t prod;          
};

typedef struct sbuf_t myData;
myData buff;

void *producer( void *dummy ) 
{
    (void)dummy;

    printf("prod ready \n");
    int s;

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&buff.prod);
        s=rand()%2;

        if( !s )
        {
            buff.sent++;
            kill( 0, SIGUSR1 );
        }

        else // if( s )
        {
            buff.sent++;
            kill( 0, SIGUSR2 );
        }

        //sem_post(&buff.prod);
    }

    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end thread: producer


void *consumer1( void *dummy ) 
{
    (void)dummy;

    //signal(SIGUSR1, handler1);
    printf("waiting 1\n");

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait( &buff.con1 );
        // do something
        //sem_post( &buff.prod );
    }

    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end thread: consumer1


void *consumer2( void *dummy ) 
{
    (void)dummy;

    //signal(SIGUSR2, handler2);
    printf("waiting 2\n");

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait( &buff.con2 );
        // do something
        //sem_post( &buff.prod );
    }

    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end thread: consumer2


void handler(int signum)
{
    sem_post(&buff.prod);
    if(signum==SIGUSR1)
    {
        //sem_wait(&buff.con);
        puts("Caught 1");
        buff.received++;
        buff.SIG1++;

        sem_post(&buff.con1);
    }

    else if(signum==SIGUSR2)
    {
        //sem_wait(&buff.con);
        puts("caught 2");
        buff.received++;
        buff.SIG2++;

        sem_post(&buff.con2);
    }
} // end signal handler: handler2


int main( void )
{
    pthread_t threads[ MAX_THREADS ];
    buff.SIG1=0;
    buff.SIG2=0;
    buff.sent=0;
    buff.received=0;
    int index;


    sem_init(&buff.con1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&buff.con2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&buff.prod, 0, 0);

    signal(SIGUSR2, handler);
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);

    for (index = 0; index < NP; index++) 
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[index], NULL, producer,NULL);
    }

    for (index = 0;index < NC1;index++) 
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[index+4], NULL, consumer1,NULL);
    }

    for (index = 0;index < NC2;index++) 
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[index+6], NULL, consumer2,NULL);
    }

    for( size_t x=0; x<MAX_THREADS; x++ )
    {
        pthread_join( threads[x], NULL );
    }
} // end function: main
```

HOWEVER, the methods to handle signals to threads does not use `kill()`  as that is for processes.

rather the code should use functions similar to::

```
int pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t *restrict cond, pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex);
int pthread_cond_signal(pthread_cond_t *cond)
```

The signaled thread should block on a `pthread_cond_wait()` call until another thread sends a signal using `pthread_cond_signal()`, with the same condition variable.

Considering the analogy with signals delivered to processes, this is a bit different because the signaled thread has already suspended its execution waiting for a signal, unlike a process that simply gets interrupted and goes on.

Comment: I've tried with adding a wait() at the end of main, and with a loop defined as while(1){}, but then the threads  stop after one signal, and GDB gives me this at the end                                                                                                      Program received signal SIGUSR1, User defined signal 1.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff77f6700 (LWP 5666)]
consumer1 () at lab3.c:62
62  }
(gdb) 
Continuing.
Caught 1
Caught 1
Caught 1
Caught 1
[New Thread 0x7ffff4ff1700 (LWP 5671)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff47f0700 (LWP 5672)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff3fef700 (LWP 5673)]

Comment: the wait() functions are for when a separate/child process exits, usually where that child process was created via a call to fork() I've edited my answer with some suggestions on using `pthread_join()` and `pthread_exit()` and on using `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal()`

Comment: I inserted an edit of the code that use the `phread_join()` and `pthread_exit()`   What happened to that EDIT?

Answer (score -1):

For you example, you are creating your producers before your consumers.    Also in your producer, you are using a random number generator to determine if you issue USR1 or USR2.  Your description gave the impression you wanted two of each (versus some random mix totaling 4) which is what I see the code doing for you.

Comment: I want 2 threads responding to each USR1 and USR2, but it to be random which one the producer issues.  What do you mean by a mix totaling 4?  Shouldn't it have the producers taking turns going through the loop, because of the semaphore, and run until it's terminated from the terminal, because that's what I want it to do?  Sorry if i'm not being descriptive enough, but I'm new to threads and signals.  Also when I run it with GDB it exits with a code 0377.

Comment: this does not answer why everything exits (almost) immediately, which is what the question ask. so this is a poor answer.